# Working with bash ANSI color escape characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, bash, ansi-escape

I am working with the following string:

```
\e[48;5;15mText\e[0m
```

When I print the string using the bash shell I get text with the background and foreground colorized. I want to manipulate this string **(including the individual characters in the escape sequence)** in Ruby. When I pass this string from the command line to Ruby or when I use it directly in my Ruby script the escape character "disappear."

**Ruby Script**

```
puts("\e[48;5;15mText\e[0m".chars.to_a)
```

**Expected Output (the dots represent blank spaces)**

```
 \
 e
 [
 4
 8
 ;
 5
 ;
 1
 5
 m
 T
 e
 x
 t
 \
 e
 [
 0
 m
```

**Current Output (the dots represent blank spaces)**

```
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 T
 e
 x
 t
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

Since I am using the string in a Ruby script and my objective is to manipulate the string (including the escape characters) I feel that I should be able to run `escaped_string.chars.to_a` on a string and get the output of the individual characters in that string. I have been able to do this in both bash and python scripts with no problems.

**Questions**
1. Why don't I see these escape characters?
2. What settings do I have to turn on to "see" these escape characters?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I've updated the question with my expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You don't see escape characters because the terminal emulator intercepts them to change colors and stuff and doesn't print them. That is the whole point of escape characters. There are almost always no "settings" you can change to get the terminal emulator to print them, but that is obviously dependent on which particular emulator you are using.

One way to see the characters would be to do this instead:

```
"\e[48;5;15mText\e[0m".chars.each {|char| p char }
```

Comment: I get the same thing if I try to display the characters using this method.

Comment: You mean you get the same output? That shouldn't happen, did you copy the code I have exactly?

Comment: My mistake. I ran `escaped_string.chars.each { |char| puts(char)}`. Which gave me the output above. What you have written works, however it doesn't allow me to manipulate the characters in the string.

Comment: I looked at your expected output. To get that, try `"\e[48;5;15mText\e[0m".gsub("\e", "\\e").chars.each {|char| puts char }`. I think that you are misunderstanding the fact that the character \e is a single character, and is in no way a combination of \ and e.

Answer (score 0):

They are not just escape characters, they are character sequence.
Try this instead:

```
puts("\e[48;5;15m")
puts("Text".chars.to_a)
puts("\e[0m")
```

Your existing code effectively prints this:

```
puts("\e\n[\n4\n8\n;\n5\n;\n1\n5\nm\nT\ne\nx\nt\n\e\n[\n0\nm")
```

Thus, the escape character sequence is broken.

Comment: I assume that the `\n` are carriages. In which case, that what you have written is exactly what I would like to print. However, what gets printed is `puts(" \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \nT\ne\nx\nt\n \n \n \n ")`.